# getting exception "The type initializer for 'emgu.cv.cvinvoke' threw an exception."

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, emgucv

#### almost tried every solutions from the internet solutions and sources.

i have the code that works fine for the x64 bit OS while x32bit OS generates exception : "The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception."

i have followed almost solutions from the internet still didn't get rid of the problem.

i have tried to put unmanaged dlls to the execution file directory.
i have build in target framework x86.
i have also tried the dlls to put into c:\windows\system32.

almost every solutions.
also tested demo projects still getting same problems.
it has run perfect on the x64bit OS but gives runtime exception "The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception."

i am using emgucv library to do some image processing. i have earlier used emgu cv library but never encountered this error. almost tried every solutions from the internet solutions and sources.
here is my sample code from the demo project.

```
private void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String FileName = @"E:\Demo\EmguCv-Histogram-01-master\S\ResizedImages\dblbig.jpg";
            Image<Bgr, Byte> InputImage;
            InputImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(FileName);
            mainImage = InputImage; //webcamCapture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
            if (mainImage == null) return;
            processedImage = mainImage.InRange(new Bgr(120, 0, 0), new Bgr(256, 70, 70));
            processedImage = processedImage.SmoothGaussian(9);
            CircleF[] circles = processedImage.HoughCircles(new Gray(100), new Gray(50), 2, processedImage.Height / 4, 10, 400).SelectMany(u => u.Select(s => s)).ToArray();
            foreach (var c in circles)
            {
                if (txtLog.Text != "") txtLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);


                CvInvoke.Circle(mainImage, new Point((int)c.Center.X, (int)c.Center.Y), 3, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), -1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LineType.AntiAlias, 0);
                mainImage.Draw(c, new Bgr(Color.Red), 3);
            }
            imageBox1.Image = mainImage;
            imageBox2.Image = processedImage;

        }
```

Comment: The error is likely due to not finding the correct native dlls. What specific library are you referencing? If you reference [emgu.CV.runtime.windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV.runtime.windows) using nuget it should all work out. Or the corresponding runtime for whatever platform you are using. You might need also need to install vcredist when deploying.